# Using a sub query in column list

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to create a query that would count how many records were created in the last 7, 14 and 28 days.  My result would return something like:

```
7Days  14Days  28Days  
21     35      56
```

I know how to for each timepsan e.g. 7 days, but I do I capture all three in one query?

```
select count(*) from Mytable
where Created > DATEADD(day,-8, getdate())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also not pretty, but doesn't rely on subqueries (table/column names are from AdventureWorks). The case statement returns 1 if it falls within your criteria, 0 otherwise - then you just sum the results :

```
select sum(case when datediff(day, modifieddate, getdate()) <= 7
                then 1 else 0 end) as '7days',
       sum(case when datediff(day, modifieddate, getdate()) > 7
                     and datediff(day, modifieddate, getdate()) <= 14
                then 1 else 0 end) as '14days',
       sum(case when datediff(day, modifieddate, getdate()) > 14
                     and datediff(day, modifieddate, getdate()) <= 28
                then 1 else 0 end) as '28days'
from sales.salesorderdetail
```

**Edit:** Updated the datediff function - the way it was written, it would return a negative number (assuming modifieddate was in the past) causing all items to fall under the first case. Thanks to Andriy M for pointing that out

Comment: This is the most efficient way to do this.  There are no reason to write sub-queries and they so much slower.  This query does a single pass over the data, very fast and efficient.

Comment: for better performance you should create an index on Created field and instead of `datediff(day, getdate(), Created) <= 7`, use `Created<=datediff(day,-7,getdate())` to force index seek.

Comment: Is `modifieddate` supposed to be earlier or later than `GETDATE()`?

Comment: This doesn't work with my data, the other two answers do.  I get 721 under 7Days, but 0 under 14 and 28

Comment: @fenster, I think @Andriy M has pointed out the issue. The datediff function should use modifieddate before getdate() as in: datediff(day, modifieddate, getdate()). I'll update my answer. Dalex also has a great suggestion

Comment: Thank you. The only issue with it now is that it reports records created between 7 days and 14 days.  Records created in the last 14 days should also include those created within the last 7 days.  But I get the idea of the query thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the prettiest code in the world, but it does the trick. Try selecting from three subqueries, one for each range.

```
select * from 
(select COUNT(*) as Cnt from    Log_UrlRewrites where CreateDate >= DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())) as Seven
inner join (select  COUNT(*) as Cnt from    Log_UrlRewrites where CreateDate >= DATEADD(day, -14, getdate())) as fourteen on 1 = 1
inner join (select  COUNT(*) as Cnt from    Log_UrlRewrites where CreateDate >= DATEADD(day, -28, getdate())) as twentyeight on 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
(
  select count(*)
  from Mytable
  where Created > DATEADD(day,-8, getdate())
) as [7Days],
(
  select count(*)
  from Mytable
  where Created > DATEADD(day,-15, getdate())
) as [14Days], 
(
  select count(*)
  from Mytable
  where Created > DATEADD(day,-29, getdate())
) as [28Days]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  [7Days]  = COUNT(CASE UtmostRange WHEN  7 THEN 1 END),
  [14Days] = COUNT(CASE UtmostRange WHEN 14 THEN 1 END),
  [28Days] = COUNT(CASE UtmostRange WHEN 28 THEN 1 END)
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    UtmostRange = CASE
      WHEN Created > DATEADD(day,  -8, GETDATE()) THEN  7
      WHEN Created > DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE()) THEN 14
      WHEN Created > DATEADD(day, -29, GETDATE()) THEN 28
    END
  FROM Mytable
) s
```